# Custom Adapter notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, xml

I have studied all the issues related to this problem, but I haven't found a solution.

The project works as follows: I create a customListView (in Main2.clas) from an XML file (http: //.../data.xml) on the web server. A single entry (playStatus) in the XML file is updated every 15 seconds on the web server. I check for updates in this application every 15 seconds (in UpdateXML.class). If data.xml has been updated since creation of customListview, I want to update the entry in cutomListview.

But the following error returns:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Main2.class

```
    public class Main2 extends Activity {
    int playStatus;
    String Adi,online ,Logo ,msUrlx ;
    public int ax;
    ArrayList<String> onlineKontrol;
    public ListView defaultList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        defaultList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview5);
        CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,MainListOlustur());
        defaultList.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        UpdateXML guncelle = new UpdateXML();
        guncelle.execute();

    }

        public ArrayList<MainList> MainListOlustur(){

            ArrayList<MainList> defaultList = new ArrayList<MainList>();
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://.../data.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("kanal");


                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);


                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                    NodeList adiList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("adi");
                    Element adiElement = (Element) adiList.item(0);
                    adiList = adiElement.getChildNodes();

                    NodeList logoList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("logo");
                    Element logoElement = (Element) logoList.item(0);
                    logoList = logoElement.getChildNodes();

                    NodeList msUrlList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("msurl");
                    Element msUrlElement = (Element) msUrlList.item(0);
                    msUrlList = msUrlElement.getChildNodes();


                    NodeList onlineList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("online");
                    Element onlineElement = (Element) onlineList.item(0);
                    onlineList = onlineElement.getChildNodes();

                    NodeList playStatusList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("playStatus");
                    Element playStatusElement = (Element) playStatusList.item(0);
                    playStatusList = playStatusElement.getChildNodes();



                    Adi = ((Node) adiList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                    online = ((Node) onlineList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                    Logo = ((Node) logoList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                    msUrlx = ((Node) msUrlList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                    playStatus = Integer.parseInt(((Node) playStatusList.item(0)).getNodeValue());


                    defaultList.add(new MainList(Adi,online, Logo, msUrlx,playStatus));


                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML READING ERROR-MAIN = " + e);
            }
        return defaultList;
        }


    public void setCheck(int a, String playStatus) {
       int mainListViewResult =  Main2.this.MainListOlustur().get(a).getPlayStatus();
        Log.e("DURUM",a+") "+playStatus+"-"+mainListViewResult);
        if (mainListViewResult != Integer.parseInt(playStatus))
        {
            Log.w("DURUM",a+"-"+playStatus+"-"+mainListViewResult);
            MainListOlustur().set(a,MainListOlustur().get(a)).setPlayStatus(View.VISIBLE);

            CustomAdapter myAdapter2 = new CustomAdapter(this,MainListOlustur());
            defaultList.setAdapter(myAdapter2);
myAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        }
    }
```

UpdateXML.class

```
public class UpdateXML extends AsyncTask{

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();


private void startTime() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 15000);
}
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 15000);

        try {

            URL url2 = new URL("http://.../data.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db2 = dbf2.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc2 = db2.parse(new InputSource(url2.openStream()));
            doc2.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("kanal");

            Main2 runC = new Main2();

            for (int iXml = 0; iXml < nodeList2.getLength(); iXml++) {

                Node node2 = nodeList2.item(iXml);

                Element fstElmnt2 = (Element) node2;
                NodeList playStatusList2 = fstElmnt2.getElementsByTagName("playStatus");
                Element playStatusElement2 = (Element) playStatusList2.item(0);
                playStatusList2 = playStatusElement2.getChildNodes();
                String playStatus2 = playStatusList2.item(0).getNodeValue();


                runC.setCheck(iXml,playStatus2);

              // Log.e("DURUM","XML L = "+iXml+") " + playStatus2);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DURUM","XML READING ERROR-UpdateXML = " + e);
        }

    }
};
}
```

CustomAdapter.class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private java.util.List mListListesi;
    private String listeler[];
    TextView textViewOnline;
    MainList mainList;
    String streamURL;
    int playStatus;


    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, java.util.List kisiler) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mListListesi = kisiler;
    }

    public void updateList(java.util.List kisiler) {
    kisiler.clear();
    kisiler.addAll(kisiler);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListListesi.size();
    }


    @Override
    public MainList getItem(int position) {
        return (MainList) mListListesi.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


@Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View satirView;

        satirView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.satir_layout, null);
        TextView textViewKanalAdi = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.kanalAdi);
        textViewOnline = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.online);
        final ImageButton playBtn = (ImageButton) satirView.findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        ProgressBar loader = (ProgressBar) satirView.findViewById(R.id.playStatus);
        final TextView fullText = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.fullText);
        final Long itemID;

        itemID=getItemId(position);


        mainList = (MainList) mListListesi.get(position);

        listeler = new String[]{mainList.getkanalAdi()};
        streamURL = mainList.getMsurl();

        playStatus= mainList.getPlayStatus();

        textViewKanalAdi.setText(mainList.getkanalAdi());
        textViewOnline.setText(mainList.getOnline());

        return satirView;

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.net.tv">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main2"
                    />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TV"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TvFull"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TvFull" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

TvFull.class

```
public class TvFull extends Activity{

private static final String TAG = null;
VideoView videoView, videoView22;
ProgressDialog progDailog;
String myuri,msurlPlayer,str;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tvfull);

    Bundle degiskenler=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(degiskenler != null){

        msurlPlayer = degiskenler.getString("msurl");

        Log.e("---msurl---",msurlPlayer);
    }
    else{
        Log.e("---msurl---","NULLLLLLL !!");

    }
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2); 


        myuri=msurlPlayer;

        videoView.setVideoPath(myuri);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                videoView.start();


                   progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);

                    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            progDailog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });


            }

        else {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Connection error !")
            .setMessage("The device must have an internet connection to use the application!")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    finish();
                }
             })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
             .show();
        };



        ;       
}




@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
   final TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBaglantiKontrol);
    videoView22 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2); 
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");

        if (videoView22.isPlaying()){
            videoView22.pause();
            txt1.setText("Stopped");


            final Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                private long time = 0;

                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    time += 1000;

                    if(time==3000){

                        Log.d("Timer", "OK!" + time);
                        txt1.setText("");
                    }
                        else{
                             h.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                        }
                    ;

                }
            }, 1000); 


        }
        else if(videoView22.isPlaying()==false) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                videoView22.start();
                txt1.setText("Playing");


                final Handler h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    private long time = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        time += 1000;
                        Log.d("Timer", "Player Notification:" + time);
                        if(time==3000){

                            Log.d("Timer", "OK !" + time);
                            txt1.setText("");
                        }
                            else{
                                 h.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                            }
                        ;

                    }
                }, 1000); 


            }

        else {


            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Connection error!")
            .setMessage("The device must have an internet connection to use the application!")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    finish();
                }
             })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
             .show();


        };


        }
        }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        videoView.stopPlayback();


    super.onDestroy();

}


}
```

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml or tell us, which activity gets started first! It doesn't seems to to been Main2.

Comment: Alex, first activity is Main2. I sending is AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: the manifest says, that TV is the first activity, that is launched, `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`.

Comment: post your "TV.class", I think we will find the error there.

Comment: Now I see, I didn't public Main2 activity. I corrected  it.

Comment: Alex, I deleted some parts to make the codes simpler. I have an onClickListerner in CustomAdapter. Here I'm sending a URL variable to TVFull with the "msurl" variable.

PlayerIntent.putExtra ("msurl", streamURL);